# Iterate over files in certain directory without loops in Java

Tags: java, file, loops, iteration

What is the best way to iterate on filed in a specific folder, but without loops? i.e, the for loop will end when all the files be checked once.

My example code (with loop):

```
        File dir = new File(svnClient.getDestinationPath().getAbsolutePath());
          for (File child : dir.listFiles())
          {
            report.report("File name: " + child.getName());
          }
```

Comment: without loops? your example contains an enhanced for loop...

Comment: *Why* would you want to do this without any loops? Your question is unclear...

Comment: To iterate, you need a loop. What is the problem in doing it the way, you suggested?

Comment: Sounds like homework, the answer being recursion

Comment: Why you do not want to use loop? You could do this with recursion but loop is more easy to read and understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion:

```
public void myMethod(){
     File dir = ...;
     List<File> files = Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles());
     recurse(files.iterator());
}

private void recurse(Iterator<File> iterator){
     if (iterator.hasNext()){
          File file = iterator.next();
          report.report(file.getName());
          recurse(iterator);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Abuse the `listFiles(FileFilter filter)` method, put your logic in the callback and ignore the return value.

```
File dir = ...
dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    boolean accept(File child) {
        report.report("File name: " + child.getName());
        return false;
    }
});
```